# How do i get my .csv data file to be aligned properly in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have been having this issue where after importing data from a csv file using the commands

```
> mydata = read.table(file.choose(), header = TRUE)
> attach(mydata)
> mydata
```

my data appears as

```
Tail_Length.Wing_Length.Gender
1                       180,278,1
2                       186,277,1
3                       206,308,1
4                       184,290,1
5                       177,273,1
6                       177,284,1
7                       176,267,1
8                       200,281,1
9                       191,287,1
10                      193,271,1
11                      212,302,1
12                      181,254,1
13                      195,297,1
14                      187,281,1
15                      190,284,1
16                      185,282,1
17                      195,285,1
18                      183,276,1
```

what can i do to have each variable stick to each section as well as fix titles to not have periods in between?

Please help soon thank you

Comment: If it is a .csv file, then you should try the `read.csv()` function.  It should handle separating the columns by the comma better then the generic `read.table()`

Comment: Use `read.csv()` or `read.table(..., sep=",")`.